# A data structure which keeps elements in sorted order, supports fast insertion and calculation of maximum difference between consecutive elements

Tags: c++, data-structures

I can store the elements in STL set for O(logN) insertions and calculation of maximum consecutive difference in O(NlogN). Is there a faster way to do this. I don't want the code. Just some ideas for implementing this DS. Thanks for your help.

Comment: balanced binary tree insertion is O(log n) and using in order traversal for max consecutive difference is O(N).

Comment: @rpattiso Yes I had that solution in mind but using STL set was easier so I didnt use this. Is it possible to be faster than this?

Comment: So you want something that's sorted, yet faster than O(log N) insertion time or faster than O(N) to look at every element?

Comment: @chris I was hoping there might be a clever way to avoid the need for traversing the entire DS for calculating the max. difference.

Comment: Cache what nodes give the max-consecutive difference. If a new insertion  modifies the difference between the cached nodes and makes it smaller than recompute using O(n). The other cases are O(1) updates to the max and still O(log n) insertion.

Comment: you could use a binary tree and a max heap with an entry for each consecutive pair. This should be log(n) for insertion and constant time max.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just write a wrapper around the STL set. Every time you insert, after the insert, get the next highest key and compute the difference. If it's greater than the current maximum, replace it and store the keys that added up to this maximum.

Insertion would still be O(log n).
Getting the maximum would be O(1).

When deleting a key, see if it's among one of the keys that you used when you computed the maximum difference. If it's, you have to invalidate the maximum, and find the new maximum. Just go through all the elements in sorted order, and keep a running maximum. By the end of the iteration, you would know the maximum in O(n).

So deletes in the worst case take O(n).